# Побочные эффекты при вызове printf (переменное число аргументов в Си)

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Есть такой код:

```
int i = 5;
printf("%d %d %d", i++, i++, i++);
```

Вывод: `7 6 5`
Почему происходит именно такой вывод? Сказали, связано с переменным количеством аргументов.

Comment: потому что это UB чистой. Тут нет точки следования. Но параметры обычно "с конца" вычисляются, чтобы в стек запихать удобнее

Comment: @pavel На i386 аргументы на стеке, но на AMD64 могут через регистры  передаваться что к танцам с бубном ведёт при реализации `va_arg`.

Comment: @jfs: С каких это пор способ передачи параметров в функцию стал зависеть от аппаратной платформы?

Comment: @AnT вы вероятно какую-то мысль хотите донести (со словом "компилятор", судя по вашей истории) Сразу положительное утверждение сделайте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Очень простое объяснение - поскольку стандарт ничего не говорит о том, в каком порядке вычисляются аргументы функции, компилятор делает это так, как считает нужным. Вот вы и получаете `7 6 5`, можете получить `5 6 7` или, скажем, `6 5 7`... Вы получаете то, что называется **неопределенным поведением**.

Объяснение поточнее, но и посложнее - читайте литературу о *точках следования*... Например, [тут](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) или [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216189/).

Comment: 1- если верить ссылке: `f(++k, ++k)` это "undefined behavior" в C, и ["unspecified behavior" после c++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). 2- После действий, связанных с %n в printf, [есть "sequence point" в c99](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order). Правда с `++k` это не помогает.

Comment: @jfs: Фундаменальные изменения в С++ начались еще в С++11 (где `i= ++i` стало определенным), но если учесть, что они были вызваны дефектностью всей модели sequencing в С++98, то можно говорить, что С и С++ пошли диаметрально противоположными путями с самого начала. Поэтому то, что происходит в этой области в С++, к С никакого отношения не имеет. Семантика `++i` в С++ не имеет практически ничего общего с семантикой `++i` в С.

Comment: Ответ вводит в заблуждение. (А в конктексте наличия в вопросе тега [language-lawyer]  ответ грубо неправилен). Возможность получить `7 6 5` ил `5 6 7` являлось бы *неспецифицированным* поведением. В данном же случае мы имеем *неопределенное* поведение, что является принципиально отличным явлением.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, вопрос вообще никак не связан с переменным числом параметров у функции `printf`.

Во-вторых, поведение в вашем примере не определено (undefined behavior), ибо множественные побочные эффекты, воздействующие на переменную `i` (увеличение значения `i` на единицу), никак не упорядочены относительно друг друга.

Обратите внимание, что объяснять это явление *неопределенностью порядка вычисления аргументов функции* нельзя. Подобные объяснения - популярное и довольно распространенное заблуждение. На самом деле именно неопределенность порядка, как таковая, не имеет никакого отношения к возникновению неопределенного поведения в данном случае. Если выражаться "на пальцах", то тут более важную роль играет скорее то, что вычисления независимых выражений-аргументов не изолированы друг от друга и могут как угодно "переплетаться" друг с другом.

А, например, вот в таком коде

```
int foo(int *p) { return (*p)++; }

int i = 5;
printf("%d %d %d", foo(&i), foo(&i), foo(&i));
```

порядок вычисления аргументов тоже не специфицирован, но (!) никакого неопределенного поведения здесь нет. Поведение просто не специфицировано. Выражаясь неформально, причина этого как раз в том, что выполнения тел функций в двух независимых вызовах не могут быть "переплетены" - они упорядочены относительно друг друга, пусть в данном случае и неизвестно как.

Обратите внимание на эту тонкость: в вашем примере побочные эффекты *не упорядочены вообще*, а моем примере они *упорядочены неспецифицированным образом*. Это - разные вещи. В вашем случае поведение не определено, в моем примере - поведение не специфицировано.

Именно в моем примере вы можете получить и `5 6 7`, и `7 6 5`, и т.д. Поведение не специфицировано, но ограничено четко оговоренным набором возможных вариантов. В вашем же коде может произойти абсолютно что угодно, вплоть до отказа компилятора компилировать ваш код или до хрестоматийного "форматирования жесткого диска" и вылета еще более хрестоматийных "nasal demons".

Comment: По крайней мере `gcc -O3` в Linux X86_64 придерживается другой точки зрения, что можно увидеть в `movl $5, %r8d;
 movl $6, %ecx;
 movl $7, %edx` перед вызовом `printf` (особенно учитывая то, что сама `i = 5` просто отсутствует в сгенерированном коде)

Comment: @avp Не понимаю, что именно вы увидели в сгенерированном gcc коде. О какой "другой" точке зрения вы ведете речь? "Другой" по отношению к чему? И какие могут быть вообще "точки зрения" в ситуации, когда поведение не определено или не специфицированно? Или вы просто хотите заметить, что форматирования жесткого диска gcc решил не делать?

Comment: Ну, с какой-то степенью натяжки, интерпретацию программы (вычисление ее результата) в процессе компиляции можно назвать и поведением (конечно, скорее это поведение авторов программы, закодированное в ней). И абсолютно не важно, считает ли стандарт такую ситуацию "не определено или не специфицированно". /  В данном случае совершенно очевидно, что спиcок аргументов printf вычисляется справа налево с учетом изменения значения переменной (чисто логической, поскольку в результирующем коде физически в памяти ее просто нет)

Comment: @avp: Во-первых, если пытаться делать такие идущие выводы о поведении gcc на основе такого тривиального примера - получится только бред сивой кобылы. Никакой определенности компилятор GCC в таких контекстах не предоставляет, даже уровня конкретной реализации (не говоря уже о том, что даже если бы такая определенность была, она бы  все равно к вопросу не относилась вообще никак). Ваше "совершенно очевидно, что спиcок аргументов printf вычисляется справа налево" - это не более чем наивные домыслы из области "безногий таракан не слышит" из диссертации Василия Ивановича в известном анекдоте.

Comment: Во-вторых, ваши попытки опять притянуть сюда за уши "порядок вычисления аргументов" вызывают лишь недоумение. Порядок вычисления аргументов тут никакой роли и не играет и к вопросу никак не относится - я эту тему авторитетно и окончательно закрыл в своем ответе. Повторяться не буду. Если вам что-то в ответе не понятно - не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте. Не надо вместо прямых вопросов создавать шумовой фон в комментариях через какие-то случайные, ничего не значащие примеры.

Comment: В данном случае я о конкретном примере и говорю. Сообщаю (не вам, конечно) что реально происходит.

Comment: @avp: Ваше "реально происходит" - это примерно как написать программу из единственного вызова `rand()` и потом рассказывать истории о том, что возвращаемое `rand()` значение вполне определено, и расписывать, что там внутри "реально происходит". Да, мы все понимаем, что компьютеры по своей сути - машины детерминистические и конечном итоге действительно "реально происходит" что-то конкретное. Но к чему это здесь? Вопрос ясно помечен, как вопрос о языке С.